# Is ARM Cortex-A8 pipeline 13 stage or 14 stage?

Tags: arm, cortex-a8

If you see this popular pipeline diagram of ARM Cortex-A8 given in one of ARM [presentations](http://esd.et.ntust.edu.tw/downloads/2012_embeddedApplication/ARM%20Archi%20RichardGrisenthwaite.pdf). It is clear that the instruction fetch stage takes 3 cycles, yet the first cycle is *sort of discounted*. But, why? Any thoughts?

Thank you...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From somewhat hidden paper on [Cortex A8](http://www.arm.com/files/pdf/A8_Paper.pdf):

> > The fetch pipeline begins with the F0 stage where a new virtual address is generated. This
> >     address can either be a branch target address provided by a branch prediction for a previous
> >     instruction, or if there is no prediction made this cycle, the next address will be calculated
> >     sequentially from the fetch address used in the previous cycle. Note that the F0 Fetch stage is not counted as an official stage in the 13 stage main integer pipeline. **This is because ARM processor pipelines have always counted stages beginning with the Instruction Cache access as the first stage.**